# SQL syntax error when inserting data into multiple tables

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-insert

I am trying to insert data into multiple tables using two insert queries between a `BEGIN;` and `COMMIT;` but I am getting a syntax error as below:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; it seems the error is around: 'INSERT INTO company ( name, street, zip, place, phone, ' at line 2

This is my query:

```
BEGIN;
INSERT INTO company (name, street, zip, place, phone, contact, email, logo)
  VALUES('".$name."', '".$street."', '".$zip."', '".$place."', '".$phone."', '".$contact."', '".$email."', '".$file."');
INSERT INTO users (username, password)
  VALUES('".$username."', '".$pass."');
COMMIT;
```

I am not sure where the error lies..

My PHP query as requested in the comments:

```
$addcompany = "
    BEGIN;
  INSERT INTO company (name, street, zip, place, phone, contact, email, logo)
      VALUES('".$name."', '".$street."', '".$zip."', '".$place."', '".$phone."', '".$contact."', '".$email."', '".$file."');
  INSERT INTO users (username, password)
      VALUES('".$username."', '".$pass."');
  COMMIT;";
  $addcompany = $conn->query($addcompany);
```

When echoeing my query:

```
BEGIN;
INSERT INTO company (name, street, zip, place, phone, contact, email, logo)
VALUES('test', 'test street 123', '3235DE', 'Rotterdam', '2356235235', 'testcontact', 'test@test.nl', '/home/website/public_html/logos/test.jpg');
INSERT INTO users (username, password)
VALUES('testuser', '$2y$10$M2vO60OuvmNxsmzbCIGhB.4EgQ55Qid/DPGAC3BYs/I2Twj8Afo5q');
COMMIT;
```

Comment: why do you need double quotes in values ?

Comment: @Ven To make PHP read them as variables, my query is surrounded in double quotes.

Comment: can you paste your php query please i .e  @sql query

Comment: @Ven Added at the bottom of my question.

Comment: You need to add single quotes before and after each literal value when forming the SQL. Bad: `VALUES(England)`, good: `VALUES('England')`

Comment: @EzLo When I change that, I get the following error: `You have an error in your SQL syntax; it seems the error is around: 'INSERT INTO company ( 'name', 'street', 'zip', 'place', 'p' at line 2`

Answer (score 1):

You will need escape character `'` for PHP variables to treat value as string, try this by passing sql parameters and `print @sql` first before executing it

```
$addcompany = 
    'BEGIN
  INSERT INTO company (name, street, zip, place, phone, contact, email, logo)
      VALUES( '''+ ".$name." +''', '''+".$street."+''', '''+".$zip."+''', 
              '''+".$place."+''', '''+".$phone."+''', '''+".$contact."+''', 
              '''+".$email."+''', '''+".$file."+''');
  INSERT INTO users (username, password)
      VALUES('''+".$username."+''', '''+".$pass."+''');
  COMMIT'
  $addcompany = $conn->query($addcompany);
```

Comment: I get a 500 internal server error when using this code. I've noticed there is a `;` missing at the end but even when adding that I keep getting the 500 error. I've also got another query which updates two tables using a `join`, I add my variables the same way as in my question and that query works. Maybe this is better practice but I don't think it is where the error lies.

Comment: if this doesn't work, it means you have issue with one of  the variables in PHP. You could see query is parsed, ensure all variables are defined with correct datatype, you dont need ; in the query

Comment: I echoed my query and added it to my question, maybe you can see if there is an error.

Comment: instead of echo try this `if( $stmt === false ) {
    var_dump(sqlsrv_errors);die;
}`. I cant see error within the statement

Comment: I don't see anything when var dumping that.

Comment: Capture error log  from 500 error, i guess we missing something simple here

Answer (score 1):

It seems that $conn->query() only supports a single query. multi_query() is a way you could try. I've found that here: https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_insert_multiple.asp

Answer (score -2):

The sql syntax for inserting multiple records into a table is as follow,

```
INSERT INTO MyTable (Column1, Column2) VALUES(Value1, Value2), (Value1, Value2)
```

try this

Comment: I don't want multiple records into one table, I want data into multiple tables.